# How can you include http://foo.local in CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: amazon-s3, cross-domain, cors

I'm using `*`, but apparently that's not enough. I'm trying to upload a file from a client browser. It works when the client's URL is `localhost:3000` or `foo.com`. It's not working when the URL is `http://meteor.local`. I've tried changing the third line to `<AllowedOrigin>http://meteor.local</AllowedOrigin>`, but get the same error.

[image]

The browser error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error text was misleading – error was not due to the header sent by s3. Adding an access rule to Cordova fixed it. (In meteor, add it with `App.accessRule('http://meteor.local');` in `mobile-config.js`.)